# The reason behind a WRONG solution to a linear programming problem

Tags: linear-programming

> I have two different solutions for  the following LPP:
>     "Suppose that $f(x)=ax+b$.If $f(0)\leq2,f(1)\geq0,f(2)\leq4$ find maximum value of $f(10)$"
>   Solution 1(Correct):
>      $$f(10)=10a+b=9(2a+b)-8(a+b)\leq 9\times4-8\times0=36$$
>   Solution 2(Incorrect in fact):
>   $$2a+b\leq4 , 0\leq a+b \Rightarrow 2a+b\leq 4+a+b \Rightarrow a\leq4,b\leq 2$$
>   $$\Rightarrow 10a\leq40 \Rightarrow 10a+b\leq 42$$
>   I DO know the second result is not optimum and so wrong,but DO NOT understand why??

Please help!

Comment: Adding two constraints is hardly optimal.  Say we had $x≤2,x≤4$.  If you add those you get $2x≤6$ or $x≤3$ which is true (of course) but not optimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can graph the points $(0,2)$, $(1,0)$ and $(2,4)$, and then consider that we want a line passing between these points, and reaching the highest possible value at $x=10$. It's clear that the best such line will pass through the points $(1,0)$ and $(2,4)$, so you see that the $b\le 2$ bound does not really play a role in the optimal solution.

---

Considering this as a linear programming problem in the variables $a,b$, we have three contraints, which provide a triangular feasible region in the $ab$-plane. The object function will be optimized at a vertex, so we consider all three:

**1.** $b=2, a+b=0\implies (a,b)=(-2,2)\implies 10a+b=-18$

**2.** $b=2, 2a+b=4\implies (a,b)=(1,2) \implies 10a+b=12$

**3.** $a+b=0, 2a+b=4\implies (a,b)=(4,-4)\implies 10a+b=36$

---

As for what went wrong in your second solution.... it's true that $a\le 4$ and that $b\le 2$, and it is true that $10a+b\le 42$, however, we can't actually obtain equality there, because we can't have $a=4$ and $b=2$ *at the same time*. This would violate the condition that $2a+b\le 4$. Looking at that condition, if $b=2$, then $a\le 1$, while if $a=4$ then $b\le -4$.

Comment: Is there any pure algebraic(not using graph) explanation of what has gone wrong in the second solution?

Comment: Hmm. I'm thinking about it. Meanwhile, I've provided an explanation with more of the flavor of linear programming.

Comment: Does my last comment, in my edited answer, help?

Comment: Thank you dear Tony, very elaborative!